# Make jQuery not discard certain elements

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to parse some HTML using jQuery, like this simple example:

```
$('<html><body><div><p>Test</p></div></body>')
```

Now, the resulting object is a bit of a letdown.
When I use the .html() function, I should get everything inside the root element.

Unfortunately, jQuery discards `<html>`, `<body>` & `<head>` tags.

So I get:

```
$('<html><body><div><p>Test</p></div></body>').html()
"<p>Test</p>"
```

Instead of the body.
It sees the first  as the root element.

I can use this:

```
$('<html><body><div><p>Test</p></div></body>')[0].outerHTML
"<div><p>Test</p></div>"
```

But I still don't have the  tag I wanted to parse.

So, how can I get around this?
Can I create a new jQuery dom window object, somehow?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, even with Vanilla.JS

Comment: @JanDvorak - It works for me in vanilla JS: `document.createElement('body')` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're using this, but a solution (not sure if best) for your problem would be use the method `.append()`

```
$('<html>').append('<body>').append('<div>').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

This will create a `<html>` tag and will fill it with the other elements.

Comment: It works to some extent, yes. But I need to parse an entire, given string. Not append pieces later. And once you add attributes to the html tag like this, it stops working

Answer (score 1):

When you pass jQuery an HTML string, it creates a document fragment, not a whole document.  As such, it won't have the parts you're asking about such as `<body>` or `<head>`.

You can create something different like an iframe if you want all those parts.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, this works perfectly in both Chrome and Firefox:

```
$('<html>').html('<html><body><div><p>Test</p></div></body>')
```

Adding in a `<head>` tag doesn't break it either.

Once you add a `<body>` tag to the original selector, it stops working:

```
> $('<html></html>')
[<html>​</html>​]
> $('<html><body></body></html>')
[]
```

Comment: This is the best method so far, but it will always return a body and a head tag, even when it's not given.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that jQuery doesn't allow you to do this.  However, you can treat the document as XML and parse it that way:

```
$.parseXML('<html><body><div><p>Test</p></div></body></html>').childNodes[0]
```

The `$.parseXML` creates an XML document, and `.childNodes[0]` will be the `<html>` node.

Comment: That's an interesting thought! And it would work well on XHTML, but unfortunately not all HTML is valid XML.